# Android Gridview onclick Event is giving Fatal Exception

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have a gridView which is populating image text etc now i just want to make all the gridview clickable 
so i tried making it

```
gridView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    Log.i("The clicked item is:"+position, null);

                }

            });
```

But the grid view is not working when i click the gridview instead of showing me the position in logcat it will tell as fatal exception.

```
06-02 05:52:49.887: W/dalvikvm(3085): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a9aba8)
06-02 05:52:49.977: E/AndroidRuntime(3085): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-02 05:52:49.977: E/AndroidRuntime(3085): Process: com.coded.sandeep, PID: 3085
06-02 05:52:49.977: E/AndroidRuntime(3085): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.coded.sandeep; is package not installed?
06-02 05:52:49.977: E/AndroidRuntime(3085):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:516)
06-02 05:52:49.977: E/AndroidRuntime(3085):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4317)
06-02 05:52:49.977: E/AndroidRuntime(3085):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-02 05:52:49.977: E/AndroidRuntime(3085):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
06-02 05:52:49.977: E/AndroidRuntime(3085):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
```

Comment: post your logcat then.

Comment: why null in log? change that with some string and post logcat too

Comment: try this  `Log.i("The clicked item is:",String.valueOf(position));`

Comment: @SimplePlan logcat posted when i click this error would pop up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass null as a parameter in `Log.i()`. Pass two valid string params.

Something like : `Log.i("Clicked Position is : ", Integer.toString(position));`

Answer (score 0):

It should be more in the terms of

```
Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "The clicked item is at: " + position);
```

So that the Tag and the Message aren't a mixed blob.